# NoSuchElementException when looking for a match in a List

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream, option-type

The following old-fashioned, simple code works fine (traverses a list of strings, and returns true, as there should be a match):

```
public boolean isMatched() {
  List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("str1", "str2", "str3");
  String matchString = "str1";

  for (String str : stringList) {
    if (StringUtils.equals(str, matchString)) {
        return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Now, I want to do the same thing, but use Java 8 instead. I have this so far:

```
public boolean isMatched() {
  List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("str1", "str2", "str3");
  String matchString = "str1";
  return (stringList.stream().filter(str -> StringUtils.equals(matchString, str)).findFirst().get() != null);
}
```

With this second method, I'm getting the following error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present [junit] at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135)
```

Why am I getting this error and what should I do to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Optional.get()` is *only* to be used when you know there's an actual value there.  If there is no value, it throws NSEE, as you've found.

It looks like you want `.findFirst().isPresent()` instead, or as discussed below, `anyMatch(predicate)`.

Answer (score 4):

`Optional.get()` throws an exception if there is no element present. It does not return `null`.

If you want a way to get the element, or `null` if none is present, it's `orElse(null)`.

However, for your situation I would use `anyMatch`:

```
return stringList.stream().anyMatch(matchString::equals);
```

Comment: Good point, showing the right stream operation and that there is no need for a 3rd party library function, but still, `return stringList.contains(matchString);` is even simpler…

Answer (score 1):

If you want any single element using kotlin from list using filter without getting
this kind of error try like this

```
 var myObject = list.filter { it.your_key.equals("your_value") }.singleOrNull()
```

Then check if Your object is not null and perform operation on that like

```
myObject?.your_key
```